# MVC 3 Pass multiple ints / collection via ajax to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

On my form I have several hidden fields with the same name (RemoveId)

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="RemoveId" />
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="RemoveId" />
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="RemoveId" />
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="RemoveId" />
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="RemoveId" />
```

I would like to pass checked items (int(s)) to a controller via ajax/json

How would i do it?
thanks

Comment: you can pass it as an array, dont you ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is something that should help

Using getElementsByName on the name "RemoveId" will give you an array

```
var list = document.getElementsByName("RemoveId");

var arrId = [];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    arrId.push(list[i].value);
}
```

Pass this list of id's prepared to the controller

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "@Url.Action("PostArray")" %>",
       data: {idArray: arrId},
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(msg){console.log(msg)}
    });
})
```

and here is how your controller should look like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostArray(int[] idArray)
{
    // do your thing..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="RemoveId" />
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="RemoveId" />
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="RemoveId" />
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="RemoveId" />
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="RemoveId" />


<input type="button" value="do" class="send" />

<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function () {
        $(".send").click(function () {
            var myValues = [];
            $("[name = 'RemoveId']").each(function (index, element) {
                myValues.push($(element).val());

            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Method",
                data: { myValues: myValues }
            });
        });

    })
</script>



        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Method()
        {
            var b = Request["myValues[]"].Split(',').ToList();
            return null;
        }
```